# Исключение при записи данных в массив, состоящий из списков

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Разрабатываю программу, которая будет искать нужный элемент при помощи хэш-таблицы. Хэш-таблицу организую путём создания массива, состоящего из ЛОС(Линейных односвязных списков) 
Объявление структуры:

```
struct LOS {
    int inf;
    LOS* next;
};
```

Код самой программы достаточно прост в переменную sourcelen пишу длину числового массива, в котором будут находиться исходные данные, в x - буду записывать элементы массива(если длина массива будет менее 5), если более, то массив заполнится при помощи датчика псевдослучайных чисел. Далее при помощи функции Maximum найду наибольшее значение элемента в массиве hasharray. После этого вычисляю размер массива, состоящего из ЛОС. и с использование hashFunc заполню массив, состоящий из ЛОС.

```
int main()
{    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int sourcelen = 0;;
    int x = 0;
    int m;

    cout << "Введите размер массива = ";
    sourcelen = control(sourcelen);
    int* hasharray = new int[sourcelen];

    if (sourcelen > 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sourcelen; i++) {
            srand(time(0));
            hasharray[i] = rand();
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Введите элементы массива" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sourcelen; i++) {
            x = control(x);
            hasharray[i] = x;
        }
    }

    m = Maximum(hasharray, sourcelen) /2;
    int k = 0;
    k = (int)(sourcelen / m);
    if (k < 9)
        k == 9;

    LOS** list = new LOS*[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        list[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    hashFunc(list, hasharray, sourcelen, m);
    cout << "Вывод" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        while (list[i]->next) {
            cout << list[i]->inf << " ";
            list[i] = list[i]->next;
        }
    }
```

Проблема возникает в функции hashFunc

```
void hashFunc(LOS ** list, int *i, int size, int m) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int t = (i[j] % m);
        list[t]->inf = i[j];
        list[t] = list[t]->next;
        list[t]->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Выбрасывает исключение на строке

```
list[t]->inf = i[j];
```

Ну могу понять что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `k == 9` - наверное здесь должно быть присваивание?

Comment: да, спасибо, только начало кидать теперь исключение на строку list[i]->next = NULL;

Comment: Это случается когда в предшествующей операции `list[i]->next` будет `NULL`. Таким образом происходит обращение по нулевому указателю. Как вариант сделать проверку перед перед `list[i]->next = NULL`. Хотя наличие этого присваивания вобще сомнительно.

Comment: понял, спасибо, исправил, а вот возник вопрос по поводу функции hashFunc он все-таки ругается на строку присвоения значения. list[t]->inf = i[j]; почему так происходит? и как это исправить?

Comment: В функции `main` вы неправильно выделили память под `list`. `LOS** list = new LOS*[k]` - значит выделение памяти под массив **указателей**, а не объектов `LOS`. Вам нужно в следующем за этой инструкцией цикле для каждого объекта выделять память `list[i] = new LOS()`. Или изначально создать `list` как массив объектов `LOS`, т.е. `LOS* list = new LOS[k]`

Comment: но если изначально создать list как массив объектов LOS, то я не смогу пробегать каждому из элементов списка массива, или я чего-то не понимаю? Просто пытался до этого реализовать именно через массив элементов LOS и не выходило, была ошибка при переходе на следующий элемент. А сейчас, через массив указателей с правильным выделением памяти всё же ругается на строку `list[t]->next = NULL;` не пойму в чем проблема... Вроде и читал статьи про списки и указатели, но видимо не совсем понимаю как они работают.

Comment: С масивом объектов будет точно такая же работа, за исключением того, что вместо `->` будете писать `.`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86491/discussion-between-i-burykin-and-acade).